# 短い黒髪に、高くも低くもない平均的な身長。

Tags: grammar

I need help with the grammar of this sentence from a light novel:

> 短い黒髪に、高くも低くもない平均的な身長。

1. What is the purpose of に after 黒髪? Is it a conjunction particle?
2. Does the く after 高 and 低 make them adverbs? If so how does it affect the verb です (which I assume is the implied verb)
3. I don't understand the use of もない in the sentence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This に is a listing particle. See: [Particle に to enumerate things?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12188/5010)

高くも低くもない平均的な身長 is the same as 高くもなくて低くもない平均的な身長, or "an average stature which is neither big nor small". See: [What is the correct grammar for "neither x nor y"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/37021/5010) / [How would you say "Something isn't X, but isn't Y as well."](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48324/5010)

- 高い身長: "big stature" ("tall height" is more literal but this is probably unnatural in English, so please bear with this)
- 高くない身長: "stature that is not big"
- 高くも低くもない身長: "stature that is not big nor small"

The omitted verb after 身長 is indeed だ/です (or [をしている](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11360/5010)), but it has little to do with the grammar above.

> 短い黒髪に、高くも低くもない平均的な身長(だ/をしている)。
> [He/She] has short black hair, and an average stature that is neither big nor small.
> [He/She] has short black hair, and is neither tall nor short.